# Sorting XML data in gridview

Tags: asp.net, xml, c#-4.0

I am trying to display sorting data in gridview from XML.

Operation of sorting is successful, but now how can I display all sorted data in gridview.

**XML File**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProjectList>
  <Business>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Name>Rajan</Name>
    <Mobile>123456</Mobile>
    <Emailaddress>rajan@yahoo.co.in</Emailaddress>
    <Date>24/01/2014</Date>
    <Project>ttpl</Project>
  </Business>
  <Business>
    <ID>12</ID>
    <Name>nitant patel</Name>
    <Mobile>123456</Mobile>
    <Emailaddress>nitant@yahoo.co.in</Emailaddress>
    <Date>27/01/2014</Date>
    <Project>ttpl</Project>
  </Business>
  <Business>
    <ID>10</ID>
    <Name>Rajan10</Name>
    <Mobile>123456</Mobile>
    <Emailaddress>rajan@yahoo.co.in</Emailaddress>
    <Date>24/01/2014</Date>
    <Project>ttpl</Project>
  </Business>
</ProjectList>
```

**C# code:**

```
XElement ProjectList = XElement.Load("Project.xml");
IEnumerable<XElement> ordered =
ProjectList.Elements().OrderBy(Business => int.Parse(Business.Element("ID").Value));
    foreach (XElement element in ordered)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine(element.ToString());
    }

    gvdata.DataSource = ordered.ToList();
    gvdata.DataBind(); //GIVE ME ERROR
```

ERROR is :  The data source does not support server-side data paging.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that the default Gridview may be trying to page the data...or at least, set it up for paging.

Try adding the 'AllowPaging="false"' attribute to your GridView tag, like so:

```
<asp:GridView ID="cantankerousgv" runat="server" AllowPaging="false">
    //other GV stuff...
</asp:GridView>
```

Default behavior is often at the root of these kinds of issues.